# What is the Advantage of Using an Array of `mutex`s on a Critical Region?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm looking at some code that uses an array of `mutex`s for the critical region of some code:

```
void alter(int item_nr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(items_sem[item_nr]));
    items[item_nr] = 1; // Assume this array is in shared memory
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(items_sem[item_nr]));
}
```

Each thread entering this function has an `item_nr` that it passes to the function.  There are exactly the same number of threads entering this function as the number of items in the array, so each thread only accesses one item and it accesses the same item each time it enters this thread.

I'm new to parallel coding, so this concept doesn't make much sense to me.  I figured that you would only want one `mutex` guarding some shared memory so other threads can't access it, but with an array of `mutex`s, wouldn't it just lock for one thread and not the others?

Comment: why not use `std::mutex` ?

Comment: @TheUnknown, I would prefer that, but that is not an option for this code.  Not my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a different mutex for each array element means that if two threads want to access different elements of the array, they they don't have to wait for each other. The above code will only cause one thread to wait for another if both threads are trying to access the same `item_nr`.

If you are guaranteed that each different thread already accesses a different element of the array, then I am not sure why you need any concurrency control at all.

Comment: So it is ok for shared memory to be accessed by multiple threads in this situation since the array has different array memory locations for each cell, technically making each cell separate memory as long as each thread isn't accessing other cells at once (which is what the code is preventing).  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, having different threads accessing different memory locations should be fine. It might be a bit dangerous, because if your assumption that different threads never access the same element is false, or if one of your threads deletes or moves the array for instance, then there can be problems.

Comment: @MartinCook `array` is contiguous in memory, it can't be moved. what you need to care might be about the shuffling of the machine's instruction set, which can be resolved by using some available built-in functions in both windows or unix.

Comment: @TheUnknown *it can't be moved* Sure it can. The minimal code currently posted doesn't preclude code somewhere else using something like `realloc()` to relocate the `items` array if it needs to be resized.  We don't know what `items` actually is, nor how it was created.